# How to Improve Press Release Distribution To News Bots On Public Company Website

Tags: seo, html, structured-data

I have a website for a publicly traded company that has been issuing press releases about once a month, however none of these releases are showing up on any of the major stock watch apps/sites.

Let me know if there is something I can do with perhaps structured data? Or something I can put in the head of the pages to help make these releases visible to bots.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too general and vague. Yes, it is possible to represent the content of a web page with structured data, but this data is highly dependent on the content that you do not tell us about.

Answer (score 2):

Structured data offers different possibilities to make your content better machine-readable. But it is not a tool or method to gain the content spreading.

To do so you should run usual content marketing campaigns, connect your business with press release aggregators, multiplicators and influencers in your vertical and so on.

Don't run into delusion, some code on your page will share your content with the world. It is the hard manual job to spread your news.